# Removing select characters from a string

Tags: java, string, methods

I'm a student trying to figure out a problem.
I need to create a method that removes any characters found in a specified string from another string.
So if `String str = "hello world" and String remove = "eo"`
the method would return `"hll wrld"`.

The way my solution is set up the resulting string gets printed out a bunch of times which is something I don't want.  Is there an easy fix for this or do I have to rework the method?

```
class StringStuff{
        public static void main (String [] args){

        String str = "This is a string that needs to be changed";
        String remove = "iaoe";

        System.out.println(removeChars(str, remove));

        }

    public static String removeChars(String str, String remove){
        String newStr = "";
        for(int i=0;i<remove.length();i++){
            for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++){
                if(str.charAt(j)!=remove.charAt(i)){
                    newStr = newStr+str.charAt(j);
                }
            }
        }        
        return newStr;
    }
}
```

UPDATE

Thanks for the responses, I figured out another "newb" way inspired by the solutions you provided.

```
public static String removeChar(String str, String remove){
      String newStr = "";
      boolean match = false;
      for(int i = 0; i<str.length(); i++){
         for(int j=0; j<remove.length(); j++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == remove.charAt(j))
               match = true;
         }
         if(match == false)
            newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);
         match = false;
      }
      return newStr;
   }
```

Comment: I think you want to switch the order of the loops.

Comment: @squiguy: This alone won't fix the error.

Comment: @jlordo I know.  This is why I pointed it out in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that the use of the `replaceXXX` methods is not allowed.

Firstly the `for` loops are the wrong way round. The first loop needs to iterate over the original `String`.

The next problem is that the nested `for` loops append a character to the new `String` for *each* character of the `remove` String provided that the characters don't match. This produces `hllo worldhell wrld`.

Therefore the solution is not to iterate over the `remove` `String`. [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) is used for character checking.

```
public static String removeChars(String str, String remove) {
   String newStr = "";
   for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
      if (remove.indexOf(str.charAt(i)) == -1) {
       newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i);
      }
   }

   return newStr;
}
```

A further improvement can be made by using `StringBuilder` rather than `String` for `newStr`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
return str.replaceAll("[" + remove + "]", "");
```

as long as `remove` doesn't contain any characters that have to escaped within a regex character class.

Comment: See [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)). I would rewrite this as `str.replaceAll(String.format("[%s]",Pattern.quote(remove)), "")`

Comment: @A.R.S.: Won't help. The `\Q` and `\E` will be inside the character class and lose their special meaining.